# phpMyAdmin CCS rendering issue

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, azure-web-app-service

Am trying to deploy phpMyAdmin as PHP Web App on Azure.

Repository is on Azure DevOps
Deploymnet to Azure is streamlined and no errors while deploying.

But rendering of phpMyAdmin seems issue with CSS files.  When logged in this is how it renders.

[image]

[image]

Comment: For the record, I could read your domainname. ^_^ I've found this thread on the matter, try running yarn install: https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/14731   - other than that, I'm stumped.

Answer (score 0):

1. You may use `Advanced tools` to check your site directory to see if the themes folder exists.

[image]

Then check under debug console, cd into the path `site\wwwroot\`

[image]

2. However, I suggest you use `Extensions` to add phpMyAdmin extension to you web app.

[image]

After the extension is added successfully, you will be able to see it in extension list. Then you can go the phpMyAdmin page by clicking the `Browse` link

[image]

By the way, to use phpMyAdmin extension, you need to add an MySQL connection string to your web app. The extension will use it.

[image]